# How to join and tag depending on condition

Tags: r, datatable, dplyr

I have a data frame which have 24 hours for each id like below:

```
library(data.table)


DT=data.table(id=c(rep(1,24),rep(2,24),rep(3,24)),
             hour=c(rep(0:23,3)),
             val=c(rep(c(18,36,27,18,36,39,99,99,72,81,54,72,18,9,36,27,18,90,36,27,18,45,54,63),3)))
```

Then I also have a data table which has each id's rush start and end hour like below:

```
c=data.table(id=c(1,2,3),start=c(3,6,9),end=c(9,12,4))
```

I have to append a column in data table a as rush and then tag where it falls in the range of each id's rush hour or not .Like for id 1 the rush hour is 3 to 9 (3,4,5,6,7,8,9) so all records with these rows in DT should be tagged with a column rush=1 and rest records with rush=0 for rest.

I tried like this

```
setkey(c, start, end)
DT[,hour_replica:=hour]
result <- foverlaps(DT, c, by.x=c('hour','hour_replica'), 
                    by.y=c('start', 'end'))
```

But it throws an error

**All entries in column start should be <= corresponding entries in column end in data.table**

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I always appreciate effort in questions that include code to reproduce problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple way could be:

```
DT[c, rush := as.numeric(start <= hour & end >= hour), on="id"]

DT
#     id hour val rush
# 1:  1    0  18    0
# 2:  1    1  36    0
# 3:  1    2  27    0
# 4:  1    3  18    1
# 5:  1    4  36    1
# 6:  1    5  39    1
# 7:  1    6  99    1
#.......so on
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `tidyverse` - I haven't used the data.table package, so I went with something I knew.  You might need to switch your `data.table` format to `data.frame` or `data_frame` - either would work, I just don't know about the `data.table` format.

I also changed the name of your rush data - using a name `c` is a really bad idea - it could mess up a lot of standard calls to the `c` function!

```
DT=data_frame(
  id=c(rep(1,24),rep(2,24),rep(3,24)),
  hour=c(rep(0:23,3)), val=c(rep(c(18,36,27,18,36,39,99,99,72,81,54,72,18,9,36,27,18,90,36,27,18,45,54,63),3)))

rush=data_frame(id=c(1,2,3),start=c(3,6,9),end=c(9,12,4))

library(dplyr)

DT %>% left_join(rush) %>%
  mutate(rush = hour >= start & hour <= end) %>%
  select(-(start:end))
```

Answer (score 1):

Using non-equi join from `data.table`

```r
library(data.table)
DT=data.table(id=c(rep(1,24),rep(2,24),rep(3,24)),
             hour=c(rep(0:23,3)),
             val=c(rep(c(18,36,27,18,36,39,99,99,72,81,54,72,18,9,36,27,18,90,36,27,18,45,54,63),3)))

c=data.table(id=c(1,2,3),start=c(3,6,9),end=c(9,12,4))

# join condition & create rush = 1 where they match
DT[c, on = .(id, hour >= start, hour <= end), c("rush") := 1]

# replace NA (no match) with 0
DT[is.na(rush), rush := 0]
DT

#>     id hour val rush
#>  1:  1    0  18    0
#>  2:  1    1  36    0
#>  3:  1    2  27    0
#>  4:  1    3  18    1
#>  5:  1    4  36    1
#>  6:  1    5  39    1
#>  7:  1    6  99    1
#>  8:  1    7  99    1
#>  9:  1    8  72    1
#> 10:  1    9  81    1
#> 11:  1   10  54    0
#> 12:  1   11  72    0
#> 13:  1   12  18    0
#> 14:  1   13   9    0
#> 15:  1   14  36    0
#> 16:  1   15  27    0
#> 17:  1   16  18    0
#> 18:  1   17  90    0
#> 19:  1   18  36    0
#> 20:  1   19  27    0
#> 21:  1   20  18    0
#> 22:  1   21  45    0
#> 23:  1   22  54    0
#> 24:  1   23  63    0
#> 25:  2    0  18    0
#> 26:  2    1  36    0
#> 27:  2    2  27    0
#> 28:  2    3  18    0
#> 29:  2    4  36    0
#> 30:  2    5  39    0
#> 31:  2    6  99    1
#> 32:  2    7  99    1
#> 33:  2    8  72    1
#> 34:  2    9  81    1
#> 35:  2   10  54    1
#> 36:  2   11  72    1
#> 37:  2   12  18    1
#> 38:  2   13   9    0
#> 39:  2   14  36    0
#> 40:  2   15  27    0
#> 41:  2   16  18    0
#> 42:  2   17  90    0
#> 43:  2   18  36    0
#> 44:  2   19  27    0
#> 45:  2   20  18    0
#> 46:  2   21  45    0
#> 47:  2   22  54    0
#> 48:  2   23  63    0
#> 49:  3    0  18    0
#> 50:  3    1  36    0
#> 51:  3    2  27    0
#> 52:  3    3  18    0
#> 53:  3    4  36    0
#> 54:  3    5  39    0
#> 55:  3    6  99    0
#> 56:  3    7  99    0
#> 57:  3    8  72    0
#> 58:  3    9  81    0
#> 59:  3   10  54    0
#> 60:  3   11  72    0
#> 61:  3   12  18    0
#> 62:  3   13   9    0
#> 63:  3   14  36    0
#> 64:  3   15  27    0
#> 65:  3   16  18    0
#> 66:  3   17  90    0
#> 67:  3   18  36    0
#> 68:  3   19  27    0
#> 69:  3   20  18    0
#> 70:  3   21  45    0
#> 71:  3   22  54    0
#> 72:  3   23  63    0
#>     id hour val rush
```

Created on 2018-04-01 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Answer (score 1):

```
c[DT, on = 'id'][, .(rush = as.numeric((hour >= start &
                                          hour <= end))), by = .(id, hour, val)]
```

one liner

using c, right join DT on id,

then doing rush=1/0 depend on hour/start/end,

by [id], [hour] and [val] so these 3 columns are included)

but I got a question,

for group id 3, start at 9 and end at 4, it would result 0 rush under rule 
(hour>=start & hour <=end).

I guess you wanted c(9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,0,1,2,3,4) all counted as "rush".

It's different from  hour>=start & hour<=end,

in case id=3

it is hour >=start | hour <=end

so if that's what you want, adding a if-else clause would solve it

```
 c[DT, on = 'id'][, .(rush = 
                       if (start < end) {
  as.numeric((hour >= start & hour <= end))
} else{
  as.numeric((hour >= start | hour <= end))
}), by = .(id, hour, val)]
```

hope this helps